# Docker-compose env after reboot

Tags: docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a container deployed on a docker-machine with `restart: always` as restart policy.
If I'm not wrong this should restart the container when the machine reboots.

But what happens with the environment variables?

Are they kept? And if so, where are they stored?

Thanks!

Comment: You mapped them using a env_file or environment?

Comment: Yes with an .env file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are retained with what the container was started with. You can consider below file

```
version: '3'
services:
  envtest:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c "echo X=$$X and Y=$$Y && exec tail -f /dev/null"
    restart: always
    environment:
      X: ${X}
    env_file:
      - env_file
```

**.env**

```
X=Y
```

**env_file**

```
Y=Z
```

Run the container using below and then reboot

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now change the files as below

```
X=A
Y=B
```

Then restart the system and run

```
$ docker-compose logs
Attaching to envtest_envtest_1
envtest_1  | X=Y and Y=Z
envtest_1  | X=Y and Y=Z
```

So as you see it will have the environment as well and it wont pickup any changes that happened in the source env files that you had used

Comment: Thank you. That means, it's stored in the image and could be reverse engineered.

Comment: Yes. For that you need to use docker swarm and docker secrets. Doesn't work with individual containers though

Comment: Amazing answer with a reproducible example!